# Only one passport (instead of 2) arrived in the mail

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

My parents qualified for the visa interview waiver.

They mailed both their documents with my mother as a dependent on my father.

When they received it back from the US embassy, only ONE passport with visa was mailed back (my dad's). My mother's passport never made it back.

Are they typically mailed separately?

More info:

- They mailed ONE envelope with 2 SEPARATE DS-160 forms
- For the interview waiver, I added my mother as a dependent (see attached online form that I filled out and the interview waiver confirmation that it generated)
- Only my father received an LBC tracking number via email (passport was already picked up, but mother's passport was not in it)

[image][image]

Comment: [This prior question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/145518/renewed-us-passport-did-not-receive-expired-us-passport/145520#145520) addressed a similar question, return of an old passport after renewal. It might be that the Embassy here will do the same, and return the mother's passport in a separate mailing so each passport can be tracked separately.